# Dynamically choose between chef cookbook versions

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I know that I can specify that version to run per host with `recipe[cookbook@cookbook_version]` but can I use ruby code to dynamically decide which node should run which version of the cookbook?

Comment: How do you specify it in the first case? The nice thing about Chef is it's mostly Ruby, which means you can add logic in most cases.

Comment: I currently specify cookbooks in roles with a json format so there isn't really an obvious place to add ruby logic there.